# state from ContextProvider not re-rerendered

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

I' am newbie in React and fighting with this problem for several days and just can not get how it works. Already googled tons of topics and didn't find how to solve this.
I need that number of purchases counted immediately on icon of shop around all shop app if some good added and made for this CartContext, this function works in one component, but when it used  in ContextProvider it's not re-rendered, but items counted, useEffect doesn't work in context. I see the number of my purchases only after refreshing a page. How to force React re-render state from ContextProvider ?

There is my context code:

```
import { createContext, useState, useContext, useEffect} from 'react';


const CartContext = createContext();


export default CartContext;

export const CartProvider = ({children}) => {

  let getCart = () => {
    if (typeof window !=="undefined") {
      if (localStorage.getItem('cart')) {
        return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cart'))
      }
    }
    return []
  };

  const [itemAmount, setItemAmount] = useState(getCart())


 let itemTotals = () => {
    if(typeof windows !== "undefined") {
      if (localStorage.getItem('cart')) {
        return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cart')).length
      }
    }
    return itemAmount.reduce((a, b) => {
        return (Number(a) + Number(b.quantity))
      }, [])
  };

   const [govno, setGovno] = useState(itemTotals)

   useEffect(() => {
     itemTotals()
     console.log('effect called!')
   }, [govno])

.... there is some other cart methods, they work...

let cartContextData = {
  addItem:addItem,
  updateCart:updateCart,
  getCart:getCart,
  removeItem:removeItem,
  emptyCart:emptyCart,
  itemTotals:itemTotals,
  govno:govno,
}

console.log(govno)


  return (
    <CartContext.Provider value={cartContextData}>
     {children}
    </CartContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

If I placed this logic, for example, in cart Component it works, but from CartContext is not re-rendered, but I see after refresh the page that state is changed. How re-render this state from Context ?

Here this example:

```
import React, { useState, useContext } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import CartContext from '../cart/CartContext';
import { Card, ListGroup, Button, Form } from 'react-bootstrap';
import Table from 'react-bootstrap/Table';
import TextField from '@mui/material/TextField'

const Cart = () => {

    let {govno, itemTotals, emptyCart, removeItem, getCart, updateCart} = useContext(CartContext);
    const [cartItems, setCartItems] = useState(getCart())
    console.log(cartItems)


    let itemTotal = () => {
       if(typeof windows !== "undefined") {
         if (localStorage.getItem('cart')) {
           return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cart')).length
         }
       }
       return cartItems.reduce((a, b) => {
           return (Number(a) + Number(b.quantity))
         }, [])
     };


    const handleChange = index => event => {
       let updatedCartItems = cartItems
         if(event.target.value == 0){
          updatedCartItems[index].quantity = 1
         }else{
         updatedCartItems[index].quantity = event.target.value
    }
    setCartItems([...updatedCartItems])
    updateCart(index, event.target.value)
    itemTotals()
  }

  const deleteItem = index => event => {
    let updatedCartItems = removeItem(index)
        setCartItems(updatedCartItems)
   }

  const getTotalSum = () => {
    return cartItems.reduce((a, b) => {
        return a + (b.quantity*b.price)
    }, 0)
  }



return (

<React.Fragment>


  <h6 style={{margin:10}}>Товары в вашей корзине:</h6>

  <div className="table" style={{ color:'white', backgroundColor: 'white' }}>

  <Table responsive bordered hover>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th style={{width:300}}>Фото</th>
      <th>Количество</th>
      <th>Товар</th>
      <th>Стоимость 1шт.</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  {cartItems.map((item, index) => (
  <tr key={index}>
                     <td><img src={item.image} style={{width:100}}></img> </td>
                     <td><TextField id="standard-number" label="Кол-во" type="number" value={item.quantity} InputLabelProps={{shrink: true,}}
                          onChange={handleChange(index)} variant="standard" style={{ width: 45}}></TextField>
                     <Button onClick={deleteItem(index)} style={{width:90, margin: 10}}>Удалить</Button></td>
                     <td>{item.name}</td>
                     <td>{item.price}р.</td>
                 </tr>
  ))}
</tbody>
 <h3 style={{ padding: 10, font: 'Verdana', width:300 }}> Сумма: {getTotalSum()}р. <p>{govno}в вашей корзине вот столько предметов: {itemTotal()}</p> </h3>

</Table>

</div>


</React.Fragment>
  )
}
export default Cart
```

the same logic with {itemTotal()} updates the number, but {govno} from <CartContext.Provider> is not re-rendered ? How it works?) I understand this is some feature of context, but how it solve?

Comment: off topic and it wont help u solve it but still wanted to say - why u using `let` for functions? arrow functions get recreated on every re-render. so just use `const`

Answer (score 0):

I found the decision, may be it's no good, but it works like I want.

In navbar for counting items in cart I added this method:

```
const amount = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cart'))

{amount.reduce((a, b) => { return (Number(a) + Number(b.quantity)) }, [])}
```

in context I added method for force re-render:

```
const [, updateState] = useState();
const forceUpdate = useCallback(() => updateState({}), []);
```

then I call this method after every action with card, for example:

```
let updateCart = (itemIndex, quantity) => {
  let cart = []
  if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
    if (localStorage.getItem('cart')) {
      cart = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cart'))
    }
    cart[itemIndex].quantity = quantity
    localStorage.setItem('cart', JSON.stringify(cart))
    forceUpdate()
  }
};
```